# Close a dynamic number of AutoCloseable objects in try-with-resources

Tags: java, java-8, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I am creating a variable amount of `AutoCloseable` objects in a `try-with-resources` block. At any point of exit, I want all of the allocated resources closed.

I can imagine writing something myself to do this, but is there an existing utility similar to [Python's contextlib.ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) that will close allocated resources? I would expect it to look like this:

```
try (ExitStack exitStack = new ExitStack()) {
    List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (...) {
        widgets.add(exitStack.add(new Widget()));
    }
    // use widgets
}
```

(Note: this is not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553139/close-multiple-resources-with-autocloseable-try-with-resources) because I don't know how many resources I'll have ahead of time.

**Hey close voters** I'm not asking for a library, I'm asking how you would accomplish the task of safely closing a dynamic number of `AutoCloseable`s, if there's a language feature for it, great, if there's a standard library function, also great, if I have to write my own, fine. If you'd *like* to recommend a third-party library in common use that has this in it then sure.

Comment: How can you not know how many resources *you* will be programming in?

Comment: @Frontear a list of filenames, IP addresses, etc, taken as input.

Comment: Why not use the `try-with-resources` inside the for-loop?

Comment: @lealceldeiro assume I need them to all be open at the same time. I can update to make that clearer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in class that provides that functionality. But implementing something like `ExitStack` shouldn't be that hard since it probably would just contain a collection of `AutoCloseables` and just close them in its own `close()` method (using a simple loop and catching exceptions per element).

Comment: I don't think this kind of functionality is supported, as you're effectively modifying a try-with-resource at runtime. Instead, you could iterate the collection, work with them, then manually call `close()` on each element. It might not look as pretty, but it will let you handle everything together.

Comment: or just create/implement an `AutoCloseable` that is a collection of `AutoCloseable`)

Comment: @Frontear that doesn't help with early returns or exceptions.

Comment: @Thomas I added an answer with just that, feedback appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Given that this utility does not appear to exist, I wrote one. It wraps up any thrown exceptions and then only throws if a resource's close() threw. Always closes everything before returning.

```
public class ClosingException extends Exception { }
```

And

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public final class ClosingStack implements AutoCloseable {
  public void close() throws ClosingException {
    ClosingException allClosingExceptions = new ClosingException();
    while (!resources.isEmpty()) {
      try {
        resources.removeLast().close();
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        allClosingExceptions.addSuppressed(e);
      }
    }
    if (allClosingExceptions.getSuppressed().length != 0) {
      throw allClosingExceptions;
    }
  }

  public <T extends AutoCloseable> T add(T resource) {
    resources.addLast(resource);
    return resource;
  }


  private Deque<AutoCloseable> resources = new ArrayDeque<>();
}
```

And use:

```
try (ClosingStack closingStack = new ClosingStack()) {
    List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (...) {
        widgets.add(closingStack.add(new Widget()));
    }
    // use widgets
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I'd change one thing though: instead of `ArrayDeque` I'd probabl use a `LinkedList` and the `Deque` interface. You don't need random access to the closeables so a linked list would save some resources here. :)

Comment: @Thomas: what resources do you imagine are getting saved?  ArrayDeques are cheaper in almost every way in practice.

Comment: @LouisWasserman reading other places confirms. I originally expected `ArrayDeque` to be faster

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Since you're here, I wonder if you'd comment on whether Guava's [`Closer`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closer.html) utility would be applicable here.  I get that the intention was to support the `try-with-resources` behavior without language support, but even with try-with-resources it seems to be roughly the equivalent to what's given here?

Comment: I'd create a special `Exception` subtype for this to throw.

Comment: It’s a bad style to through an unspecific `Exception` instead of the first actual encountered exception. It wouldn’t be so hard to change it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find Guava's [`Closer`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closer.html) class to be what you need here:

```
try (Closer closer = Closer.create()) {
   InputStream in1 = closer.register(new FileInputStream("foo"));
   InputStream in2 = closer.register(new FileInputStream("bar"));
   // use in1 and in2
}
// in2 and in1 closed in that order
```

The class is still marked as Beta mind you, but has appeared to stick around.  The original intent was to provide a try-with-resources experience without Java 7 language feature support, however a useful side effect is that it should work with a dynamic number of resources.

Comment: almost :/ [register](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closer.html#register-C-) takes `Closeable` not `AutoCloseable`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
<T extends AutoCloseable> void recursively(
    List<T> things,
    Iterator<? extends Supplier<? extends T>> thingSuppliers,
    Consumer<List<T>> whenEmpty) {
  if (!thingSuppliers.hasNext()) {
    // No more to create. Pass all the things to the consumer.
    whenEmpty.accept(things);
    return;
  }

  // Create a new thing, and make a recursive call. This thing gets
  // closed as the stack unwinds.
  try (T thing = thingSuppliers.next().get()) {
    things.add(thing);
    recursively(things, thingSuppliers, whenEmpty);
  }
}

// Some means of starting the recursion.
<T extends AutoCloseable> void recursively(
    Iterable<? extends Supplier<? extends T>> thingSuppliers,
    Consumer<List<T>> whenEmpty) {
  recursively(new ArrayList<>(), thingSuppliers.iterator(), whenEmpty);
}
```

Example invocation:

```
recursively(
    Arrays.asList(Widget::new, Widget::new), 
    System.out::println);
```